# Hoare program correctness

Tags: linear-programming, model-checking, correctness

Which is the easiest way to find a valid **Invariant** for a *While Program* in the Hoare program correctness verification? 
Is there a "guided" way to do that?

Comment: If you want "a valid invariant" you can always use "True". What you probably mean is a valid invariant that helps you to prove easily (!) about a program whatever you need to prove. That's non-computable in general.

Comment: I think it would help if you gave an example of a program and what you want to prove about it and also if you describe what you know about deriving invariants. Try the Dafny: http://rise4fun.com/dafny/Hello and Interproc: http://pop-art.inrialpes.fr/interproc/interprocweb.cgi web-interfaces for two examples of many many tools out there.

Comment: If you read the Manna+Pnueli book, they will talk about the basics of synthesizing invariants in a semi-automatic fashion using "top-down" or "bottom-up" methods. The programs that Vijay D mentions are also good approaches but on restricted/pre-defined types of invariants.